# Number of H1 in HTML5 era

Tags: html, tags

This should be a quick one for you.. I know that in the HTML5 era multiple h1 tags are allowed as long as they are part of sections (always using the "article" or "section" and sometimes "nav").

My question is that is it allowed to have just one single H1 outside of a section respecting the one-h1-rule per page of the pre-html5-era .. and use the rest of h1 inside the sections?

So can these two H1 tags co-exist?

```
<div id="logo">
<h1><a href="index.html">... </a></h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <article>
        <header>

            <h1 style="font-size: 2em;">Sometext</h1>

        </header>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Run your code through a validator like https://validator.w3.org and you'll see

Comment: @j08691 — Validity is a useful QA check, but while an invalid document is wrong, a valid document is not necessarily right.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML 5.2 recommendation says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#creating-an-outline):

> There are currently no known native implementations of the outline algorithm in graphical browsers or assistive technology user agents, although the algorithm is implemented in other software such as conformance checkers and browser extensions. Therefore the outline algorithm cannot be relied upon to convey document structure to users. Authors should use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.

So, while you can do as your code example shows in *theory*, in practise you shouldn't.

Comment: I can still though use multiple tags theory and practice right? Using the html5 markup always (not as shown above) ..

Comment: @justme — If you mean the hierarchy of h1 to h6 elements that has existed in all versions of HTML: Yes. That is what the quote says.

Comment: Is there any chance that the heading rank is supposed to also work within section therefore allowing multiple tags? eg. <section> ...h1 - h6 </section> ..<section> ...h1 - h6 </section> and so on ..

Comment: @justme — Yes. That's the technique which the quote says you should not use because it isn't supported.

Comment: @Quentin This is not true. Check the following. 
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824

Comment: @Billef32 — That is a long article. I fail to see where it shows that the algorithm has widespread support.

Comment: @Billef32 - That article is way out of date. You should read ["There Is No Document Outline Algorithm"](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly acceptable to use H1s the way you suggested in your question.

For example, in Bootstrap you could use this:

`<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>`

or this instead:

`<h1 class="navbar-brand">Navbar</h1>` in the nav bar.

Comment: A link to the top of the page and a main heading are not remotely equivalent.

Comment: @Quentin So what?? It's a common practice to use it that way.

Comment: I agree with @WebDevBooster

Comment: @Quentin the outline is quite common. I've used it and I've also seen it in many many big marketing and graphic design agencies websites (and I am talking for some of the best out there).

Comment: @Ricky — So you've seen people writing it. Great. People (including people working for big companies) write bad code all the time, so that doesn't prove it is good code. Have you heard a screen reader consume it properly?

Comment: @Quentin No, this isn't "bad code" in this case. In this case, it's just a matter of personal preference. But that wasn't the question. The question was whether or not it's acceptable. And it is.

Comment: @WebDevBooster — It isn't a matter of personal preference. It is a practical matter where the shiny new specification doesn't have practical support so using it will introduce accessibility problems that will make it hard for some people to use a website.